# Sparkling water won't start on Spark on Google DataProc

Tags: h2o, google-cloud-dataproc, sparkling-water

I'm trying to use H2O Sparkling Water on Google DataProc.  I've successfully run Sparkling Water on a standalone Spark, and now moved on to use it on DataProc.  Initially, I got an error about `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` not being supported, so I've gone on the master and started like this...

```
pyspark \
   --conf spark.ext.h2o.fail.on.unsupported.spark.param=false \
   --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false
```

The interaction to start Sparkling Water looks like this, once the stage gets to around 30000, it starts to grind, and then after 30 mins or so, there's a string of errors:

```
>>> from pysparkling import *
>>> import h2o
>>> hc = H2OContext.getOrCreate(spark)
18/04/11 11:56:08 WARN org.apache.spark.h2o.backends.internal.InternalH2OBackend: Increasing 'spark.locality.wait' to value 30000
18/04/11 11:56:08 WARN org.apache.spark.h2o.backends.internal.InternalH2OBackend: Due to non-deterministic behavior of Spark broadcast-based joins
We recommend to disable them by
configuring `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` variable to value `-1`:
sqlContext.sql("SET spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1")
[Stage 0:=================>                               (35346 + 11) / 100001]
```

I've tried a variety of things like:
- Deploying small (3 nodes).
- Deploying a 30 worker cluster.
- Tried running DataProc image 1.1 (Spark 2.0), 1.2 (Spark 2.2) and preview (Spark 2.2).

Also tried a variety of Spark options:

```
spark.ext.h2o.fail.on.unsupported.spark.param=false \
spark.ext.h2o.nthreads=2
spark.ext.h2o.cluster.size=2
spark.ext.h2o.default.cluster.size=2
spark.ext.h2o.hadoop.memory=50m
spark.ext.h2o.repl.enabled=false
spark.ext.h2o.flatfile=false
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false
spark.executor.memory=700m
```

Anyone have any luck with H2O on Google DataProc?

Detailed errors are:

```
18/04/11 12:08:40 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container marked as failed: container_1523445048432_0005_01_000006 on host: cluster-dev-w-0.c.trust-networks.internal. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1523445048432_0005_01_000006
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

18/04/11 12:08:48 ERROR org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler: Error sending result RpcResponse{requestId=5571077381947066483, body=NioManagedBuffer{buf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=81 cap=156]}} to /10.154.0.12:59387; closing connection
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source)
```

and later:

```
Exception in thread "task-result-getter-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.Class.newReflectionData(Class.java:2513)
    at java.lang.Class.reflectionData(Class.java:2503)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2660)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:403)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:394)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:393)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:112)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, think I solved this for myself. Sparkling Water allocates resources based on a number of settings which are non-default in Google DataProc.

I edited `/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf`, and changed `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` to `false` and changed `spark.ext.h2o.dummy.rdd.mul.factor` to `1`, which allowed the H2O cluster to start up in about 3 minutes with about a tenth of the resources.

If it is too slow starting up for you, try reducing `spark.executor.instances` from `10000` to `5000` or `1000`, although this settings affects the performance of everything else you're running on the Spark cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.  Give more memory.

Comment: The line that caught my eye was `spark.executor.memory=700m`.  I recommend making executors no smaller than 5gb each, and even that is small.